# React hooks loses state when storing an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have crated state in my react function component using

```
  console.log('reset');
  const [val, setVal] = useState(props.data.bulk_notification.overdue_notification.active);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isOverdueActive: props.data.bulk_notification.overdue_notification.active,
    isUpcomingActive: props.data.bulk_notification.upcoming_notification.active,
  });

  console.log(state);
  console.log('val', val);
```

`state` is how I would like to access things and val is the only way I have found to work.

After loading the component I see

```
reset

Object { isOverdueActive: false, isUpcomingActive: false }

val false
```

These values have been set as expected from props. Then after changing state with an onClick event I see

```
reset 
Object { isOverdueActive: true, isUpcomingActive: false }
val true

reset 
Object { isOverdueActive: false, isUpcomingActive: false }
val true
```

The code setting the state onClick is

```
  setState({ ...state, isOverdueActive: !notification.active });
  setVal(!notification.active);
```

It seems that only the state which was a simple bool was persisted across component rerender while the object was reset using the props passed down. Is there some special behavior for objects? Should objects be used in state with react hooks?

Comment: To answer the question, no there's no special behaviour for objects and you can use them in state hooks. Do you do anything else in the `onClick`? What is the `notification` you're referring to in that function? Think we'll need more context and relevant code

Comment: Post your full component code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your *new state* is dependent on *previous state*, use should use a callback in setter. (setState in this case)

```
instead of...
setState({ ...state, isOverdueActive: !notification.active });

I would use
setState(previousState => {
  const newState = { ...previousState, isOverdueActive: !notification.active }
  return newState
  );
```

When you provide a function to your setter(s), it receives the current(or previous) state as an argument.

And also agreeing with the comments above, showing more of your code would help.

Comment: Its a little hard for my to pull out more of the code but you are right, using the callback fixed it. There was another setState shortly after which I guess must have been grabbing the old state and setting it again.